# PUT method not working on Modal component in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, components, httprequest

I'm trying to make a submit form for edit a single entity (i.e. single pet) in my backend, and in order to do that, I'm making a Modal component. When I try to make a postman request, it works just fine (this is how I know it's not an API problem) but with axios.put(url, changeObject) or even the native next.js fetch method for put request, nothing happens. When I run the debug, my submitHandler function is completely omitted. I'm currently using next.js 13.2.4.

The code for the  component is the following:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Modal({ entity }) {
  const id = entity._id;
  const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/pets?_id=${id}`;
  console.log(url);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const petName = useRef("");
  const petType = useRef("");
  const owner = useRef("");

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
      const {data} = await axios({
        method: "put", //patch does not work either
        url: url,
        data: null,
        params: {
          petName,
          petType,
          owner,
        }
      });
      console.log(data.petName, data.petType);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
          Edit
        </button>
      </div>
      {showModal ? (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <h2>Editar</h2>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name_field"
              ref={petName}
              defaultValue={entity.petName}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              id="type_field"
              ref={petType}
              defaultValue={entity.petType}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              id="owner_field"
              ref={owner}
              defaultValue={entity.owner}
            />
            <button type="submit" onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>
              Save
            </button>
            <button type="reset" onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>
              Cancel
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Modal({entity}) bit is receiving data from a swr function that allows me to pass the values from origin page (i.e. a single pet data) to input fields as defaultValue.

It should update the backend entity, even if it does not render immediately on the main page (the single pet page), but it doesn't. I've tried to change the component from client side to server side, and viceversa, and nothing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, my bad, but actually, neither "put" or "patch" in method seems to work

Comment: right. probably submit is not called, only modal here: `<button type="submit" onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>` try removing that, and see if the submit gets triggered, if so, then you'll need to call them one after each